# vtiger autofill javascript

Tags: javascript, vtiger

I've followed a javascript indicated into https://discussions.vtiger.com/index.php?p=/discussion/174146/ho-to-autofill-accounts-address-in-to-trouble-tickets-custom-field/p1. I've modified it asking for a field that is indexed, and obviously this script gives me the index number. Could you please help me indicating me how to obtain this index field value?.

For instance, I've asking for an asset (this field is an ui type 10 field) but I receive only the asset_id number, not the asset name. How should I change this script to get this information?.

Best regards.

Antonio.

Comment: Please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if you can, a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Make it easy for people to help you. This will significantly increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: You can check the javascript source from http://jsfiddle.net/x6oja0ap/. This almost the same script as published into vtiger discussion forum. My problem is that this script gives me the database id, not the value. Thank you.

Comment: This is good but you are expected to create a complete runnable example in jsfiddle with html etc. Not just dumping your code. The easier you make it for people to help you, the more useful answers you will get. Please read [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As it's a javascript that works into /layouts/vlayout/modules/helpdesk/resources, in a complete vtiger system. I think I can't do an example. So please delete this question. Thank you